# how to insert field from one child record to another record

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

In opportunity tab  if the stage value is changed to closed won then one custom object having three fields id name and description after changing to closed won i have to transfer the values from custom object to quote how this can be acchived??

Comment: Hi Ganesh. Welcome to SFSE. Your question is a bit vague and a little confusing. You could really help people out by adding more details as to what steps you've tried and any code or configs that you have now. Please read these guidelines for making an effective post. Thanks! http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Here are two documents that might help you with updating fields of one object based on values in another object:

1. Cross-Object Formulas http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_cross_object.htm&language=en_US
2. Cross-Object Field Updates https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_cross_object_field_updates.htm&language=en_US

Hopefully these will point you in the right direction for updating Quotes based on custom object fields.